# R code parallelized using plyr and doMC: error message: Error in do.ply(i) : task 1 failed - "could not find function "getClass""

Tags: r, parallel-processing, cluster-computing

I'm just getting started learning how to use remote supercomputers for execution of parallelized code.  I got a lot of initial help from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14553357/parallelizing-on-a-supercomputer-and-then-combining-the-parallel-results-r) previous post, as well as one particularly helpful and patient XSEDE guy.

I'm only using one node (for the meantime), but each of its 32 cores.  I'm using doMC instead of snow, because the guy at the supercomputer is in the process of getting Rmpi running.  For now, 32 cores should be (more than) adequate for me.  My script is of the sort:

```
define a bunch of functions
load the data
call libraries
require(doMC)
require(plyr)
registerDoMC(32)

main.function <- function(data){
    *the function*
    }

results = llply(1:500, function(idx){out<-main.function(data)},.parallel=TRUE)

save(results,file="trestles_results")
```

This runs fine on my own machine (setting it to run only a few times and registering only a couple of cores).  But when I run it on the cluster, the output file shows that it ran each of the 500 iterations, but I get no output file, and I get the following error message:

```
Error in do.ply(i) : task 1 failed - "could not find function "getClass""
Calls: llply -> %dopar% -> <Anonymous>
Execution halted
Nodes:        trestles-10-28
```

Anybody have any idea what is going on here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: do you use package `methods` ?

Comment: no.  should I?  what does it do?  googling "R package methods" doesn't give me much.

Comment: No you should'nt. Just the "could not find function "getClass" and  I know that this package contains such function...

Comment: Are you using the same R core file on the HPC as on your local machine? Also check library version differences. Check loaded libraries at startup, etc; I'm betting it's a library interaction.

Answer (score 2):

for completeness sake,
*ply functions have a builtin `.paropts` where you can specify variables and packages to send to a cluster node

```
results = llply(1:500, 
          function(idx){out<-main.function(data)}, 
          .parallel=TRUE,
          .paropts=list(.export=c('data','main.function'),
                        .packages=.packages(all.available=T))
```

or you could be more selective with `.packages`, depending how complex `main.function` is. I think because you are calling `main.function` from inside the anonymous function you would need to pass `main.function` to the clusters too.

Comment: I've tried passing in a global function but it cant seem to find it. Any ideas?

Comment: @masfenix I had a typo. should have been `.export = c('data','main.function')`. you can also try `.export=ls()`

Answer (score 0):

One reason this can occur is that the environment hasn't been exported to the cores. I found one solution posted here, including sample code:

http://www.numbertheory.nl/2011/11/14/parallelization-using-plyr-loading-objects-and-packages-into-worker-nodes/